# Why cannot I set font of `xlabel` in `plotmf` in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, debugging, label

I use the example of `plotmf` function in the [document](https://www.mathworks.com/help/fuzzy/plotmf.html) and at the same time, I want to change the font of `x` label. So I use the code below:

```
fis = readfis('tipper');
plotmf(fis,'input',1)

xlabel('\fontname{宋体} 论域')
ylabel('\fontname{宋体} 隶属度')
```

But the `xlabel` shows it in its original state as `\fontname{宋体} 论域`, and the `ylabel` is what I want. The figure is below:

[image: the figure]

So why does the `fontname` command in `xlabel` not work?

## My proposition

- I change the order of `xlabel` and `ylabel` in the code, for thinking the failure may occur only at the first `label`. But it is still the `xlabel` that doesn't work.
- I use another plot function, such as `plot`. Then both `xlabel` and `ylabel` work properly.

**So I think the key point is the definition of `xlabel` of `plotmf` function.**

MATLAB R2023b.

## My method to avoid the problem (one can neglect)

Then I use another method avoiding the `fontname` in `label` using `gca` as

```
fis = readfis('tipper');
plotmf(fis,'input',1)

xlabel('论域')
ylabel('\fontname{宋体} 隶属度')

set(gca, 'FontName', '宋体');
```

And it works. But I want to simultaneously show different fonts in a `label`, such as `xlabel('\fontname{宋体} 时间\fontname{Times new roman} (s)')`, and `gca` fails.

So this is not a good method, and it doesn't explain the issue.

Comment: The issue is reproducible for me on R2021b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is likely caused by this function setting the interpreter used by the label. Each text object has an [`Interpreter` property](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.primitive.text-properties.html#d126e1697981) that can be set to `'tex'` (default), `'latex'` or `'none'`. Putting it back to the default value should fix this:

```matlab
fis = readfis('tipper');
plotmf(fis,'input',1)

xlabel('\fontname{宋体} 论域', 'Interpreter', 'tex')
ylabel('\fontname{宋体} 隶属度')
```

But an easier way to set the font is by using the `FontName` property, which not only applies to the axes as a whole, but can be set to each text object:

```matlab
xlabel('论域', 'FontName', '宋体')
```

Comment: Thanks. But if it is as your answer, how can I find the _default_(?) `Interpreter` for `xlabel` and `ylabel` for `plotmf` function? And why are the default Interpreters of the two labels designed to be different?

Comment: @SHBooKP the default is always `'tex'`. The `plotmf` function apparently changes its value for the x axis, I don’t know why.

Comment: @SHBooKP But as I said, the right way to change the font is to set the FontName property for the label.

Comment: @CrisLuengo If multiple fonts are required in the same label, setting font with `FontName` property won't work (or is there a way?).  @SHBooKP This answer correctly identifies the problem and provides the fix. `plotmf` changes the interpreter of xlabel which is unexpected behavior and seems like a bug.

Comment: @SardarUsama Indeed, if you need to switch fonts within the label, you need to use the TeX mode.

Answer (score 1):

If you need multiple fonts in the XLabel, a quick fix is to [`delete`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/delete.html) the XLabel object and then re-[`xlabel`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlabel.html) it.

i.e.

```
delete(get(gca,'XLabel'));
xlabel('\fontname{宋体} 时间\fontname{Times new roman} (s)'),
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Thank you for answering one of my questions. And another alternative way is to create a `text` fixing at x axis.

Comment: What do you mean by creating a `text` fixing?

Comment: Use `text(4,-.3,'\fontname{宋体} 论域')` instead of `xlabel('\fontname{宋体} 论域')`, **visually** playing the same role. @SardarUsama

Comment: Great if that works for you

Comment: @SHBooKP Note that `xlabel` creates a text object. Only it has specific properties that allow it to remain centered on the axes even if you zoom in on the figure, which the custom `text` object won’t do.

Comment: @CrisLuengo, well, I can get `XTick` and do an average, and get `YTick` and do a proportion for the arguments in `text`.

Comment: @SHBooKP Yes, you can. But if you later interactively zoom in or change the figure in another way, the label will not stay in its place. The solution is ok for static figures, but still more work than solving the problem properly.

Comment: @CrisLuengo, oh, sorry, I mistook your meaning when comprehending your word `zoom ` (I use Google Translation). I thought it as just the change of the quantity of the range of the axis when handling with different plots.